# is it possible to have 2 nested pivot functions in TSQL

Tags: csv, t-sql, formatting, pivot-table, ssis-2012

I am fighting with formatting using TSQL code.  I thought that maybe I can achieve what I want using PIVOT function (sql 2012) but I think I would need to nest 2 Pivots in the same query and I am not sure if that is possible.

my table looks like this:[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSss4.png)
and Ideally I would like to export to a .csv format like this [Formatted output .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk3WI.png)

I have tried using a pivot with the following code `select *
from
(
select distinct
monthnum
,monthname
--  ,Urban_rural
,performance
,Jurisdiction

```
from ##cte
 )as  src
 pivot 
    (
    avg(performance)
    for jurisdiction in ([North],[south],[east],[west])
    )piv;` but its only partly getting me where I wanted to be. [Pivot results][3].  So the questions I have are:  How do i get my output file to look like the sample using SSIS or TSQL.  Can you nest Pivot functions (or should you?)
```

Cheers!

Comment: To be frank, I would not recommend nesting the pivots. What you could do is making a staging table (ex temporal or cte) in which you "pre-aggregate" your values in such a way, that they have a common pivot-able key: `North_Urban`, `North_Rural`, `North_All`, etc. That can easily be done like `select monthnum, monthname, Urban_rural + '_' + Jurisdiction Urban_rural_Jurisdiction from ##cte union select monthnum, monthname, Urban_rural + '_All' Urban_rural_Jurisdiction from ##cte`.

Comment: Ok great!  I will try this today

Comment: it didn't work out quite as expected....I think I understand the principle but Now I have multiple Performance values for Urban, Rural and ALL (4 sets of each for every month).  monthnum monthname Urban_rural_Jurisdiction performance
1 Jan Urban_All 0.97993311036789297658
1 Jan Urban_All 0.98709677419354838709
1 Jan Urban_All 0.98786407766990291262
1 Jan Urban_All 0.98952879581151832460

Comment: I may have mixed up the Urban_rural with Jurisdiction in my previous comment. The principle would have be to generate the values for the columns North_All, South_All, East_All, West_All. From the screenshot-ed data I thought the All values are without consideration of Urban_rural. You still have to do a pivot with avg, but that can be done for the values: `[North_Urban], [North_Rural], [North_All], [South_Urban], [South_Rural], [South_All], [East_Urban], [East_Rural], [East_All], [West_Urban], [West_Rural], [West_All]`

Comment: Thank you Lakta, The format is now returning the way I wanted it to..But the values returned are not correct...Must be the way I am passing them into the pivot?monthnum monthname North_Urban North_Rural North_ALL South_Urban South_Rural South_ALL East_Urban East_Rural East_ALL West_Urban West_rural West_All
1 Jan 0.987000 0.928000 0.957500 0.980000 0.898000 0.939000 0.988000 0.940000 0.964000 0.990000 0.935000 0.962500
the performance value is not matching the actual performance but your help got me 90% of the way...Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lakta's suggestion of using a pivot table with Unions returned the results I was looking for.

> To be frank, I would not recommend nesting the pivots. What you could do is making a staging table (ex temporal or cte) in which you "pre-aggregate" your values in such a way, that they have a common pivot-able key: `North_Urban`, `North_Rural`, `North_All`, etc. That can easily be done like:

```sql
SELECT monthnum,
       monthname,
       Urban_rural + '_' + Jurisdiction Urban_rural_Jurisdiction
FROM ##cte union select monthnum, monthname, Urban_rural + '_All' Urban_rural_Jurisdiction from ##cte
```